# Getting Promise Pending in selenium with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to create bank login automation using selenium with nodejs and am stuck in Promise{pending}.

```
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');

async function main() {
let driver = await new Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .build();

await driver.get('login-url')
const name = await driver.findElement(By.name('AuthenticationFG.USER_PRINCIPAL'))
const pass = await driver.findElement(By.name('AuthenticationFG.ACCESS_CODE'))

await name.sendKeys(username)
await pass.sendKeys(password)

await driver.findElement(By.id("VALIDATE_CREDENTIALS1")).click()
await driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(driver.findElement(By.id('LoginName'))), 1000)
await console.log(driver.findElement(By.id('LoginName'))) <-- getting issue here

}
main()
```

I am trying to print username after login scraping from the page but it keep on giving Promise {pending}.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does driver.findElement(By.id('LoginName')) return a promise?

Comment: Yes, I guess so. Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As AbhinavD pointed out use:

```
main().then((result) => {
// do stuff here
})
```

Your main function is `async`, it returns a Promise. A promise is a data structure which can be either resolved, rejected, or pending. When a promise is resolved you can call the `.then()` callback on it. Here is an example which should illustrate the point:

```js
 async function test () {

  let randomvalue = 5;

  return randomvalue;
}

let returnValue = test()

// this logs the promise object
console.log(returnValue);

// this logs the actual value returned in the async function
returnValue.then((value) => {
 console.log(value)
});
```

An `async` function essentially resolves a promise with the returned value.

Promises itself is a must learn topic for anyone who wants to work with JS frequently. So [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) is a more detailed source:

Answer (score 0):

`main` function is async. You need to wait for it to complete.

```
main().then((result) => {
// do stuff here
})
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate more. I am new to this stuff.

Answer (score -1):

You need to call `getText()` to read text displayed on element.

```
let loginName = await driver.findElement(By.id('LoginName')).getText();
console.log(loginName);


await main()
```

Comment: I did but got same promise {pending}

Comment: try add `await` before `main()` when invoke it.